# Retrieve the xpub and private key of a given path (Bitcoin Core)

Tags: bitcoin-core, multi-signature, bip32-hd-wallets

How do we retrieve the xpub and the private key (for signature) of a given path (m/87h/0h/0h, for example) for legacy and descriptor wallets in Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 2):

There is no xpub in legacy wallets: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/107918/, use `dumpwallet` for private keys.

[`listdescriptors`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21500) can be used to get xpub and xprv for descriptor wallets

Comment: listdescriptors RPC returns only m/44'/1'/0'/{0,1},  m/84'/1'/0'/{0,1} and m/49'/1'/0'/{0,1}. If you want m/44'/0'/0'/{0,1} or m/87'/0'/0'/{0,1} (most commonly used for multisig), you cannot get them from this RPC.