# Could be possible to get the Xpub from a Bitcoin Core wallet using RPC commands?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, xpub

I know in the Bitcoin Core wallet there is no easy way to extract the xpub from a wallet, but maybe with the latest changes that have been made to the core (such as the exit descriptors), there are some new commands or ways that allow me to have the xpub from a wallet.

In Electrum Wallet or other wallets, that information can be taken easily, and I know that if I import my seed in these wallets I can get the xpub, but I would like to know if it is possible to do it from the Bitcoin Core wallet or not?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Core uses hardened derivation so there simply is no `xpub` to begin with, it isn't being hidden from you or obscured.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that, and from your answer, I understand that the only way to have the xpub is to export the private key into another wallet like Electrum, isn't it?.
The question is because I would like to have the xpub and create a watch-only wallet into Sentinel (for example)

Comment: There is no xpub, plain and simple. It isn’t being hidden from you, it isn’t being obscured, it isn’t unavailable due to legislation or poor faith. It does not exist.

Comment: Ok, I never said that was hidden or something like that. Maybe my English is not very clear, but I appreciate your answer.

Comment: What Claris said is correct. Since derivation is hardened, there is no xpub. Even if you'd export the xprv, other software would not be able to compute an xpub for it. This only applies to legacy wallets however. With descriptor wallets, hardened derivation is not used for the last steps (by default), and thus an xpub exists.